# AWS Security Groups: Filter by rule description

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-security-group

In late August 2017 AWS added a description field to each security group rule, which is very helpful to recognize and search for rules.
However, there is no way in the UI to change multiple rules from different security groups at the same time.

For example, suppose there are rules in different security groups to open a port for some ip address with the description "NY Office." If the ip address changes, I'd like to be able to update the rules with the description "NY Office" without knowing the previous ip address, or have to go into each rule and update it.

I am writing a little program to so just that, but it doesn't seem like there is a way to filter by a rule's description. Only by the security group description or any of the other rule fields such as ip, port, and protocol.

Anyone knows how to go about achieving this goal?

Comment: Same question here, let me know if you ever found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aws-cli, then you need to use version 1.14.34. If you execute the following command, you will notice that the description field for each rule is displayed. You can use --query with the command to get what rules you want

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids XXXXX
```

If you are using AWS-SDK-PHP, then you need to use version 3.x. take a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-11-15.html#describesecuritygroups) page and look for **describeSecurityGroups**

Comment: Thanks @saad-zaamout, I know how to get a list of the security groups. I was asking specifically about filtering the results to rules in security groups that have a description that matches a given description filter. After some more research I see that there is no way to do it with the SDK. Instead I opted to doing a manual filtering on the security groups rules in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is based on the work done at https://gist.github.com/isalgueiro/212a612fc232f1437ce88876937691d3/revisions#diff-c6d6f47361666bfba5538e6e0101bafd

###################
# Define variables#
###################
# Expect for securityGroupIds is sg-...
securityGroupIds="Insert_Your_SGID"
# Expected for ruleDescription is something like Home, or OfficeNY
ruleDescription="OfficePT"

# Retrieve my public IP
publicIP=`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`

## Find existing rule with the configured description
cidrIP=`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids $securityGroupIds | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[0].IpPermissions[] | select(.ToPort==80) | .IpRanges[] | select(.Description == "'$ruleDescription'") | .CidrIp' | tail -1f`

## Delete it, if found
if [ -n "${cidrIP}" ]; then
  aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $securityGroupIds --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 22, "ToPort": 22, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp":"'$cidrIP'"}]}]'
fi

## Add the new rule
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id $securityGroupIds --ip-permissions '[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 22, "ToPort": 22, "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": "'$publicIP'/32", "Description": "'$ruleDescription'"}]}]'
```

Taken from: https://gist.github.com/0xtf/76a1e008e655b49d5e8c4299d39df66a